# Change pyspark.df column value based on match to list item

Tags: python, list, pyspark, replace, match

I have a df like this

| List | index_in_List |
| --- | --- |
| ['a','b'] | 0 |
| ['c','d'] | 0 |
| ['d','a'] | 1 |

the `index_in_list` was creatd by finding the index in the `List`, where a string ("a") matches.
Using:

```
df = df.withColumn("index_in_List", (F.array_position(df.List, "a")))
```

Unfortunattley, when the **index is 0** as well as **when "a" does not exist**, the **resulting index is 0**.
Now, I want to make the 0 in `index_in_List` to None (Null), where `List[index_in_list]!= "a"`. Otherwise, keep the original

the result should look like this

| List | index_in_List |
| --- | --- |
| ['a','b'] | 0 |
| ['c','d'] | Null |
| ['d','a'] | 1 |

I tried several things to exchange missmatches with None:

```
    #conditions1= F.when(df["index_in_List"]=="a",df["index_in_List"]).otherwise(F.col("index_in_List",None)
    #conditions2= F.when(df["index_in_List"]=="a",df["index_in_List"]).otherwise(F.lit(None)
    #conditions3= F.when(df["List"][F.col("index_in_List")]!="a",F.lit(None)).otherwise(df["index_in_List"])          
    conditions4= F.when( df["List"].getItem([df["index_in_List"]])!="a",F.lit(None)).otherwise(df["index_in_List"])        
    #conditions5= F.when(df["index_in_List"]=="a",).otherwise(F.col(idxcolname,None)

    df=df.withColumn("index_in_List",conditions4)
```

Could you help out either with the **correct change to None** (Null)

or is there a method that **instead of 0, None is returned when finding no match**?
Thanks

Comment: what version of spark are you using? `array_position` supposed to return 1-based index and only 0 when not found. If not, is it a bug of the version? https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.2/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.array_position.html

Comment: Thanks, but pyspark is on 3.3.1  -> Latest version to date...

Comment: I am using 3.3.1 and `array_position(df.List, "a")` returns `1, 0, 2` accordingly. Try double checking your data and see if you have the same array in `df` as you described here and try `array_position` again.